# I am trying to make a more than 1 input command in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

This is my current code for a command I am working on:

```
bot.on("message", async msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}apply`)) {
        var user = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
        const loading = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Fetching your user ID...")
        msg2 = await msg.channel.send(loading)
        rapi.getUserIdFromUsername(user).then(async found => {
            if (found === false) {
                msg2.edit("test")
            } else {
                const found2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("User ID Found")
                    .setThumbnail(found.getAvatarBustImage)
                    .setDescription("We have found a User ID Linked to your account. It is: " + found.id + ". Is this you? \n [Click here to go to the profile](https://www.roblox.com/users/" + found.id + "/profile) \n \n ***PLEASE NOTE THAT IF YOU REACT WITH ✅ THAT YOUR ID WILL BE STORED FOR READING PURPOSES.***")
                msg2.edit(found2)
                msg2.react('✅').then(r => {
                    msg2.react('❎');
                });
                msg2.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '❎' || reaction.emoji.name == '✅'),
                    { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(async collected => {
                        if (collected.first().emoji.name == '❎') {
                            msg.reply("The ID has not been stored.")
                        }
                        if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
                            IDarray.push(`${found.id} || ${found.name}`)
                            console.log(found.id + " || " + found.name)
                            bot.channels.cache.get("771406620570943548").send("New ID pushed to table. Use `idarray` to see the full list. \n Roblox ID of user: " + found.id + " \n Roblox Name: " + found.name)
                            const check = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setTitle("Success")
                                .setDescription("Your ID has now been saved. \n Question 1: \n Have you had experience with this job before?")
                            msg3 = await msg2.edit(check)
                            msg2.reactions.removeAll()
                            const filter = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                            msg3.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: false })
                                .then(async collected => {
                                    const msg = collected.first()
                                    var Reply1 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                    if (msg.content === `${Reply1}`) {
                                        msg.delete()
                                        const ques2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            .setTitle("Question 2")
                                            .setDescription("Why should we choose you over other applicants?")
                                        msg4 = await msg3.edit(ques2)
                                        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id
                                        msg4.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: false })
                                            .then(async collected => {
                                                const ms = collected.first()
                                                var Reply2 = msg.content.split(' ').slice(0).join(' ');
                                                if (ms.content === `${Reply2}`) {
                                                    ms.delete()
                                                    const ques2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setTitle("Question 2")
                                                        .setDescription("Why should we choose you over other applicants?")
                                                    msg5 = await msg4.edit("test")
                                                }
                                            })
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    }).catch(() => {
                        msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');
                        msg2.reactions.removeAll()
                    });
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I am trying to make the 2nd AwaitMessages work but I can't figure it out. I have tried and tried but I need help. I have tried changing variables and constants but nothing works. I need someone to please reply and help me. I do not get any errors

Comment: Unfortunately, "does not work" is not enough for us to diagnose the problem. What's going wrong? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I do not get any errors.

Comment: So... What happens?

Comment: It does nothing.

Comment: Ok, that's weird.